# Undeclared Identifier 'MSHookIvar'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cygwin, theos, cydia-substrate

After importing `substrate.h`, i went on using `MSHookIvar` in a function from a hooked class.
Btw, I am trying to compile from Cygwin.
I am unable to compile with the following errors:

```
Tweak.xm:20:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSHookIvar'
    hookedLabel = MSHookIvar<UILabel *>(self, "_textLabel");
                  ^
Tweak.xm:20:27: error: unexpected interface name 'UILabel': expected expression
    hookedLabel = MSHookIvar<UILabel *>(self, "_textLabel");
                             ^
Tweak.xm:20:36: error: expected expression
    hookedLabel = MSHookIvar<UILabel *>(self, "_textLabel");
                                      ^
Tweak.xm:20:38: error: expression result unused [-Werror,-Wunused-value]
    hookedLabel = MSHookIvar<UILabel *>(self, "_textLabel");
```

And this is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "substrate.h"
#import "logos/logos.h"

%hook DataView

UILabel *hookedLabel;

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpg = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(handleLongPress)];
    [lpg setDelegate:self];
    [lpg setMinimumPressDuration:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:lpg];

    hookedLabel = MSHookIvar<UILabel *>(self, "_textLabel");
}

%end
```

I tried importing `logos.h` but it still doesn't help at all.

EDIT: 
I realized my substrate.h doesnt have a definition for `MSHookIvar`, what should i do?

Please do help

Answer (score 0):

i found a `substrate.h` from a googlecode user networkpx
[Link](http://networkpx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/include/substrate.h)

I replaced it with my current one and it seems to compile and work perfectly